# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Lessons#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"lessons",
> :course_id=>"1", :id=>nil, :section_id=>"1"}, missing required keys:
> [:id] Extracted source (around line #19):

```
  <div class="lesson-link">
    <%= link_to "show", course_section_lesson_path(lesson, @section, @course) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

> Rails.root: /home/kihara/classrooom11
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
> app/views/lessons/index.html.erb:19
> app/views/lessons/index.html.erb:10 Request Parameters:
>
> {"course_id"=>"1", "section_id"=>"1"}

Comment: is `lesson` object accessible in `app/views/lessons/index.html.erb` file?

Comment: @Emu is correct, seems like `lesson` is either unsaved or nil. It's trying to match a route against the `id` but it's `nil`.

Comment: looks like this in the index file <div class="lessons">
    <% @lessons.each do |lesson| %>
      <div class="lesson-title">
        <%= lesson.title %>
      </div>
      <div class="lesson-description">
        <%= lesson.description %>
      </div>
  
      <div class="lesson-link">
        <%= link_to "show", course_section_lesson_path(lesson, @section) %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>